# How to prevent the dimming of my desktop picture when enabling icons on desktop?

Tags: gnome, configuration, desktop-environments, customization, gnome-tweak-tool

I have recently noticed that when having the `Icons on desktop` feature enabled in `gnome-tweak-tool`:

[image]

That my desktop image is slightly darker than it is when the feature is disabled, and I have tested it multiple times by switching the setting on and off and it goes darker, and then to its normal light over and over again. But I don't like it going darker when I have that setting enabled, so is there any way to make it so that it does not get darker when that setting is enabled or is that just a built-in thing that I can't change?

**Information Update:**

The output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background` is:

```
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-opacity 100
org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#000000'
org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'
org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'solid'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///home/arthur-dent/Pictures/Wallpapers/Ionic_Charge.jpg'
org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background true
```

Comment: Check the behavior with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`

Comment: And add the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background`

Comment: @A.B.: The commands to turn it on and off have the same affect on the dimness of the background as the GNOME Tweak Tool GUI does.

Comment: I don't have this effect :\

Comment: @A.B.: That's very strange... So you think it might be a bug and not a feature? Or perhaps it is just hard to see on your desktop, as I may have just not noticed it before.

Comment: Can I have your wallpaper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect occurs when you use a sRGB JPG. Convert the image into RGB JPG or into a PNG and the effect/bug is gone.